# ListView Custom Sorting Logic

Tags: c#, listview, sorting

I know how to implement ListView sorting, and I have it implemented; however I am having issues coming up with the logic for this custom sorting I want to do for one of my columns. I have tried looking for examples but I just can't seem to find anything that fits what I am looking for or even point me in the right direction for the logic.

The column can contain 4 things "Dupe", "Possible Dupe", "Safe", and "None". I would like to be able to sort them based of the *state* of the item, so that at some point in time any of the 4 could be at the top of the ListView, as such the typical SortOrder.Ascending/SortOrder.Descending will not work.

I would really appreciate any help, I just can't seem to come up with logic to do this.

Comment: So you plan on having some sort of UI to set what order the states should be in?

Comment: That's what I am not quite sure about, I only have experience with doing the standard ListView sorting on Column Head click. I really have no idea how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a dictionary to contain the states and their sort order, and a UI to set the sort orders.  Then join the data source (List, DataTable, etc.) to that dictionary's key (the state) and order by the dictionary's value (the sort order).